# Is there such a thing as a 1 1/8" water spigot reducer?

Tags: hardware, hose

I'm sorry if this is a basic question, but I've been around the world and back looking for a reducer for my outdoor water spigot, which has a 1 1/8" diameter. (And to fit most hoses, I assume I'm looking for a reduction to 1".) Does anyone know where to find one, or if I should just go ahead and replace the spigot entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for: [1" female NPSH to 3/4 GHT male](https://www.google.com/search?q=1%22%20female%20npsh%20to%203%2F4%20male&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=1%22%20female%20npsh%20to%203%2F4%20ght%20male)

> The thread standard for garden hose connectors in the United States and its territories is known as "garden hose thread" (**GHT**), which is 3/4" diameter straight (non-tapered) thread with a pitch of **11.5 TPI** (male part has an outer diameter of `1 1⁄16` **inches (26.99 mm)**). –[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_hose)

`1 1/8"` pipe [does not exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_Pipe_Size). More likely, you're trying to put a 3/4" GHT hose on a 1" NPSH spigot. You're measuring the OD, standard pipe goes by ID (e.g., 3/4" pipe has a one inch Outer Diameter).

According to [jgbhose.com](http://www.jgbhose.com/technical-reference-literature/threading-information.asp), female NPT is not compatible with male NPSH (although I *think* it might work well enough). You could *try* NPT if you can't find any NPSH fittings in the isle. Just make sure that whatever it is, it has a rubber washer.

---

Most of this is research and also some guess work, as I've never dealt with 1" garden hose. Verify your fitting size and thread type before making any purchases.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback - that was very helpful. I'll check if this works out and report back.